# Symfony2 entity form field and its attribute name

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have created a list of contact with Symfony2.3 forms using the form builder and the entity type. 
I have checked the options 'expanded' and 'multiple' so that it gives me a nice list of entries with checkboxes. I now try to add functional testing to it through phpUnit but unfortunately the list generated give me the same attribut name for all entries. IDs make use of the entry id and so, are unique. Here is an example of what I get:

Entry 1:

- id="form_entry_1"
- name="form[entry][]"

Entry 2:

- id="form_entry_2"
- name="form[entry][]"

... and so on.

Questions:

- Is there a way to reference data on forms using ID attributes instead of name with phpUnit?
- ...or, what can I do so that Sf2's form of type 'entity' deals with name attribute properly?

Thanks a lot for any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: {{ form_widget(form.name, {'full_name': 'form[entry]['~unique.id~']'}) }}